# issue with friend functions in c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, friend

I have defined the following class with some friend functions in **an h file**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

namespace mtm {
static bool compareIsBigger(double a, double b) {
    const double EPSILON = 1e-10;
    return fabs(a - b) < EPSILON ? false : a > b;
}

static bool areSame(double a, double b) {
   const double EPSILON = 1e-10;
   return fabs(a - b) < EPSILON;
}
class Security  {
private:
    char* name;
    double stockValue;
    int stockAmount;
    double* quarterAnalyse;
    void operator =(const Security&) = delete;
    static bool nameIsInCaps(const char* name);
public:
    //// *other functions not relevant*
    friend bool operator==(const Security& s1, const Security& s2);
    friend bool operator!=(const Security& s1, const Security& s2);
    friend bool operator>=(const Security& s1, const Security& s2);
    friend bool operator<(const Security& s1, const Security& s2);
    friend bool operator>(const Security& s1, const Security& s2);
    friend bool operator<=(const Security& s1, const Security& s2);
    friend bool operator>=(const Security& s1, const Security& s2);
};
}
```

I have then implemented them **in a c file** (that includes the header of course):

```
#include "Security.h"
#include "exception.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace mtm;

bool operator==(const Security &s1, const Security &s2) {
    if (areSame(s1.stockValue, s2.stockValue) && s1.stockAmount == s2.stockAmount
        && !strcmp(s1.name, s2.name))
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool operator!=(const Security &s1, const Security &s2) {
    if (!(s1 == s2))
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool operator<(const Security &s1, const Security &s2) {
    if (compareIsBigger(s1.stockValue, s2.stockValue))
        return true;
    if (areSame(s1.stockValue, s2.stockValue)) {
        if (s2.stockAmount > s1.stockAmount)
            return true;
        if (s2.stockAmount == s1.stockAmount) {
            if (strcmp(s2.name, s1.name) > 0)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


bool operator>(const Security &s1, const Security &s2) {
    if (!(s1 < s2) && s1 != s2)
        return true;
    return false;
}


bool operator<=(const Security &s1, const Security &s2) {
    if (!(s1 > s2))
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool operator>=(const Security &s1, const Security &s2) {
    if (!(s1 < s2))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

However, for each of these implementations, the compiler complains that these functions don't have access to private parts!

Why is that? I have declared them as friend functions!
I am using eclipse if it is of any matter.

These are the compilation results regarding this problem:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
'char* mtm::Security::name' is private  Security.h  /MTM_HW4    line 32 C/C++ Problem
'double mtm::Security::stockValue' is private   Security.h  /MTM_HW4    line 33 C/C++ Problem
'int mtm::Security::stockAmount' is private Security.h  /MTM_HW4    line 34 C/C++ Problem
ambiguous overload for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'const mtm::Security' and 'const mtm::Security') Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 183    C/C++ Problem
ambiguous overload for 'operator' (operand types are 'const mtm::Security' and 'const mtm::Security')  Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 190    C/C++ Problem
within this context Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 155    C/C++ Problem
within this context Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 156    C/C++ Problem
within this context Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 168    C/C++ Problem
within this context Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 170    C/C++ Problem
within this context Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 171    C/C++ Problem
within this context Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 173    C/C++ Problem
within this context Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 174    C/C++ Problem
bool mtm::operator!=(const mtm::Security&, const mtm::Security&)    Security.h  /MTM_HW4    line 60 C/C++ Problem
bool mtm::operator(const mtm::Security&, const mtm::Security&) Security.h  /MTM_HW4    line 63 C/C++ Problem
bool operator!=(const mtm::Security&, const mtm::Security&) Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 161    C/C++ Problem
bool operator(const mtm::Security&, const mtm::Security&)  Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 182    C/C++ Problem
candidates are: Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 162    C/C++ Problem
candidates are: Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 183    C/C++ Problem
candidates are: Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 190    C/C++ Problem
candidates are: Security.cpp    /MTM_HW4    line 196    C/C++ Problem
```

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Are there any `#if*` macros that you've omitted from the header file code you're showing here?

Comment: no im showing all there is in the header file in terms of include

Comment: Please post the exact error messages that relate to the operators in question.

Comment: PS. You said that the second file is a .c file. Could that be the case? GCC for example distinguishes these file extensions.

Comment: what does it mean that it distinguishes them? how does it affect the friendship?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the operator overloads outside of the class in the header file as well.

Comment: that didn't work, it still says the fields are private

Comment: Did you exclude the semicolon after security class in your header or is it not there in your original code?

Comment: it is there, sorry, i have excluded it, now it's there

Comment: instead of saying using namespace mtm put all of your cpp file inside of the mtm namespace with brackets.  This also requires that you used my previous suggestion and declared the operator overloads outside of the class but inside of the mtm namespace

Comment: what do you mean? copy all the content of the cpp and put in the header? i do wish to keep the c file

Comment: in your cpp file instead of saying using namespace mtm; you put namespace mtm{ all of your code in the cpp}  The compiler is having issues associating the overloads that you wrote in your cpp file and the overloads in your header file because it assumes that your overloads in the cpp file are not in the mtm namespace

Comment: that seemed to do it. why in the world the compiler wouldn't know i was overloading the header functions if i wrote "using namespace mtm"?

Comment: imagine that you had multiple using namespace *** in a cpp file.  Then imagine that two namespaces of these had the same operator== overload that took in the exact same parameters.  There is no way for the compiler can differentiate which operator== you are referring to and so it requires that you put operators inside of the mtm namespace instead of just simply typing using namespace mtm;

Comment: you're absolutely right. However, is there a more "clean" way to solve this then to include the entire cpp in the mtm namespace? does the mtm namespace in the header and the cpp count as one and the same? or two with the same name?

Comment: You could attempt to only put the operator overloads inside the mtm namespace with the brackets and also have your origional using namespace mtm; at the top of the cpp.  I believe that would work and could be viewed as "cleaner" but I have not tried it myself personally.  For all intents and purposes the mtm namespaces in the header and cpp file can be viewed as one in the same, by including the brackets the implementation that you have created will be "added" to the mtm namespace declared earlier in your header file